# What does `jenkinsci/slave` do when using jenkins docker slave plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to use `jenkins docker slave` plugin to run my job inside a docker container. I found that jenkins pull `jenkinsci/slave` image from docker hub. I don't understand what this docker container is used for? How does it impact my job running docker container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the plugin documentation for this which clearly lists the architecture:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-slaves-plugin

This is used for the Jenkins remote agent and your commands are not run inside it

[image: Jenkins docker plugin]